# Android DOCX4J convert docx to PDF

Tags: android, pdf-generation, docx4j

please has anybody experience / sample code to get this running on Android? I have all the JAR s installed and I am able to create a DOCX.

using

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/android/src/test/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/pdf/PdfMultipleThreads.java

gives me an error:

```
06-26 19:26:04.293: E/AndroidRuntime(31289): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

while executing

```
    static Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();
```

thank You

Comment: Try getting https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml working, then add the FOP jars.  But you may need to jump through some hoops; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083162/fop-for-android

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jason. I got Docx to html already working. Where can I get these fop jars?

Comment: Is there any location to download already prepared FOP libaries for android?

Comment: @user1616685 I am facing the issue in "Docx to html" using docx4j. Can you help me to fix this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104305/android-docx4j-build-issue