# Android - docx4j build issue

Tags: android, build, docx, xlsx, docx4j

I am developing  an android application. In which I need to show the docx, xlsx files inside my application. I have searched in the internet and found **`docx4j`** will convert docx, xlsx files to html (or) pdf. So that I am planning to show the html return from the **`docx4j`** in the webview.

So that I have downloaded the source from [github](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml) and tried to run the sample. I made changes in eclipse.ini file as given in the link as well.

But, I couldn't execute the application. When I run the app, I am getting the following exception.

```
[2014-11-24 17:19:34 - AndroidDocxToHtml-master] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

**The detailed log :**

```
[2014-11-24 17:19:34 - AndroidDocxToHtml-master] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xml.serializer.SecuritySupport12$8) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-11-24 17:19:34 - AndroidDocxToHtml-master] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad utf-8 byte 9a at offset 00000002
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:374)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:294)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:188)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte 9a at offset 00000002
    at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.throwBadUtf8(CstString.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:143)
    at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.<init>(CstString.java:200)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
    ... 42 more
...while parsing cst 008c at offset 000002a6
...while parsing cst 0005 at offset 00000018
...while parsing org/apache/xml/serializer/utils/SerializerMessages_ru.class

[2014-11-24 17:19:34 - AndroidDocxToHtml-master] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-11-24 17:19:34 - AndroidDocxToHtml-master] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I have added the libs only one time in the app.

What may be the issue. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I did add all the jars what they given in the [github](https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml). So that I got the above exception.

Now I removed the **"serializer-2.7.1.jar"** from the workspace and then build the app. I can convert the docx to html without build issue. It is working fine now.

Comment: docx4j : I couldn't get the whole doc content such as images, tables, etc. Just it shows only the content, not the "formated content" and also it takes more time to convert to html.