# JAVA creating custom .class library file from several existing ones ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse

I was using [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) to get readable content of the several .class files in order to create a custom one, because many parts of the original libraries are not used (save space and performance)

So I read the code and started creating an eclipse library project in eclipse pasting them in.

soon apeared the first weird errors:

```
The method getLogger(Class) from the type Logger refers to the missing type Class

Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

and so on.

Does anyone has experience in creating  libraries from other libraries in eclipse? what is going wrong?

thank you.

EDIT:

it seems that several imports are not found:
error example:

```
 The import org.w3c.dom.stylesheets cannot be resolved
```

how can this be, when the original libraries are working fine? I did not remove a single class. my custom library is just a merged one with 100% the same content.

Comment: The error says it all: the class is missing. The original library seems to have it as you said it worked fine. Put `org.w3c.dom.stylesheets` and the missing rest on your class path.

Comment: this answer explained me why it is not working:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5084664/1616685